# find a string in a file and print line for multiple lines

Tags: python

So to start off I have a folder named data with .txt files in the folder that are the acronyms for each US state. These files have the top few most popular names for that year and state. A couple lines from a random file look like so

```
AK,F,1910,Mary,14 

AK,F,1910,Annie,12 

AK,F,1910,Anna,10

AK,F,1910,Margaret,8

AK,F,1910,Helen,7

AK,F,1910,Elsie,6

AK,F,1910,Lucy,6

AK,F,1910,Dorothy,5

AK,F,1911,Mary,12

AK,F,1911,Margaret,7

AK,F,1911,Ruth,7

AK,F,1911,Annie,6

AK,F,1911,Elizabeth,6

AK,F,1911,Helen,6
```

My task is to find the most popular name for a range of years given by user (the gender is also given by user. As you can see the most popular name is the first one with the new year on it. My code is as follows:

```
def getTopNames(state, gender, startYear, endYear):
    names = []
    file = open("data/" + state + ".TXT")
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if startYear and gender in line:
                names.append(line.split(","))
                if startYear < endYear:
                    startYear += 1
                    names.append(line.split(","))
    print ( lstAll )
```

This is the error I get:

```
File "C:/Python34/CS1 WORK/top_names.py", line 53, in getTopNames
   with open(file) as f:
 TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='data/NY.TXT' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

what am I doing wrong? I made sure the data file is in the same file that my .py file is in.

Comment: This task seems to have provoked several questions today; homework?

Comment: Yes, I just answered the same question, strange!

Comment: I haven't seen this one elsewhere yet today, but at least this question meets the help center's guidelines for HW questions.

Comment: This is a homework question, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to open the file twice:

```
file = open("data/" + state + ".TXT")
with open(file) as f:
```

and should be using

```
filename = "data/" + state + ".TXT"
with open(filename) as f:
```

Then, the line

```
if startYear and gender in line:
```

doesn't work as you think it does. It actually means

```
if (startYear) \ # true if startYear is non-zero/nonempty
and (gender in line): # true if the letter M/F occurs *anywhere* in the line
```

You want something like

```
items = line.split(",")
if str(startYear) in items and gender in items:
```

Comment: Your first suggestion could be made even better by using the `os.path` module: `filename = os.path.join("data", state + ".TXT")` Admittedly this is a bit picky, but since Python provides such easy-to-use functions to enable platform-independent code, why not use them?

Comment: thanks a lot for the help with the and statement! I didn't know it meant that.

Comment: Wait I tried to implement the second fix you suggested but when i did that, it told me that line was not defined. on the line of items = line.split(",")

Comment: @Isaiah: That line is meant to come as the first line in the `for line in f:` block.